# Move all non-letter characters from one string to array of char

Tags: c#, string, letter

I have a string with letters and non-letter characters. I want to use non-letter characters in the String.Split() method to split the string into words divided by non-letter characters. How can I do this? I know, there's a Char.IsLetter() method, but I think it would be stupid to execute this method in a loop for every character of the string. I need to consider as letter all the characters of the English alphabet and the apostrophe ('), all other characters are not letters. Thanks.

P.S. IsPunctuation method wouldn't work, I need something with IsLetter method. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is your friend here.

```
     var testString = "TEST.string;here";
     var nonChars = testString.Where(f => !char.IsLetter(f) && f != '\'').ToArray();
```

Edited slightly to more closely match the spec